# GWT change menuBar position

Tags: java, css, gwt, menubar

I'm having a menuBar with a sub menuBar with n-menuItems. it looks kinda like this picture: [image: sample picture]

But because of my layout I want to open the "More" option on the left side of the menu not on the right side. Is this doable with just changing the Css-File [*] (left: XXpx) or do i have to make some kind of changePopUpPosition Method ?

[*]:

```
.gwt-MenuBarPopup{
    left: 300px;
}
```

Thx for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because if you change this rule, all the elements which are using they´ll change their position as well.

So, I recommend you in your GWT´s code, get this element and apply your css rule.

About the css, under my opinion maybe changing the text-align is enought for your requirements.
Something like: `text-align: right;`

If you are happy working with JS, you can have a look into GQuery, because is quite fast have access to your element.

I have just checked in the GWT´s Showcase and is working...

[image]

Comment: ok. sorry. thats not what i meant. I meant (in your example picture) that the component with "fishing ... How to" is positioned on the left side of the menuBar.